# How to print the recursive XML data into CSV file using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

This is my sample XML data having only attributes data and having multiple child nodes,

```
<FIXML  s="...." v="....">
 <Batch ID="....">
  <MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="14" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="CONF" MarketSegmentDesc="FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%" Sym="CH0002741988" ParentMktSegmID="FBND" Ccy="CHF" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="2">
    <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="5" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
    <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
    <FlexProdEligs FlexProdEligCmplx="5" FlexProdElig="Y"/>
    <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
        <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.01"/>
        <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="5" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.01"/>
        <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0"/>
        <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1"/>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="75" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.15"/>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="347" PxRngProdCmplx="5" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.12"/>
     </BaseTrdgRules>
    <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.102" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.230" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
    <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.103" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.231" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
    <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="3" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.114.97" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.114.113" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
    <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="3" SvcLctnID1="224.0.114.96" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.114.112" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
    <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.89" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.217" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
</MktDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="158.39">
    <Instrmt ID="408805" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMPSX" MatDt="2017-06-08" MMY="201706" Mult="1" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="P" SettlSubMeth="4" PxPrcsn="2" MinPxIncr="0.01" MinPxIncrAmt="10">
        <AID AltID="1048612" AltIDSrc="M"/>
        <AID AltID="XF000001RQD8" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-08"/>
    </Instrmt>
    <MktSegGrp MktSegID="14">
    <SecTrdgRules>
        <BaseTrdgRules>
            <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="75"/>
        </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
    </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
 .
 .
 .
 .
</Batch>
</FIXML>


"<MktDef> and <SecDef>" will be continued for N number of times.
```

Sample XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:text>MktID,MktSegID,PxRngRuleID,PxRngProdCmplx,StartPxRng,EndPxRng,PxRngValu,</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch/MktDef">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(@MktID,',',@MktSegID,',',ancestor::FIXML/Batch/MktDef/BaseTrdgRules/PxRngRules/@PxRngRuleID,',',@PxRngProdCmplx,',',@StartPxRng,',',@EndPxRng,',',@PxRngValu,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java code to convert XML data to csv:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

class Xml2Csv {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        File stylesheet = new File("style.xsl");
        //File xmlSource = new File("Testing-1.xml");
        File xmlSource = new File("95FILRDF01PUBLI20170511XEUR6NJ92000.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        System.out.println(source.toString());
        System.out.println("Hello");
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("PxRngRules.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);

    }
}
```

Here I want to get the output in the format below.

```
MktID   MktSegID    PxRngRuleID PxRngProdCmplx  StartPxRng  EndPxRng    PxRngValu
XEUR    19629            75           1            0    99999.9999  0.15
XEUR    65               75           1            0    99999.9999  0.15
XEUR    66               75           1            0    99999.9999  0.15
XEUR    67               75           1            0    99999.9999  0.15
```

The problem I is I am only getting first "PxRngRules" tag data. I am unable to get the all the occurrences of "PxRngRules".

Comment: Are you only interested MktDef entries that have PxRngRules children?

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but don't create a DOM just to provide the input to a transformation. Let the XSLT processor build the tree in its own way by providing a StreamSource.

Comment: Hi NMGod, Yes I need only MktDef entries that have PxRngRules children,

Comment: Hi Michael Kay, Can you please provide me a sample program or POC to do the transformation using StreamSource. Thank you!

Comment: So, do you actually want one row for each `PxRngRules` under a `MktDef`? Will there always be at least one `PxRngRules` under each `MktDef` element?

Comment: Hi Tim, Actually I have multiple MktDef tags available in my XML and in each MktDef I have multiple PxRngRules. So what I want to print is for each MktDef, I want to read PxRngRules data. In this case MktDef value will be same for those PxRngRules. It will be continuing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your requirement, but you could try this XSLT, if you wanted multiple lines for each `PxRngRules` under a `MktDef`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MktID,MktSegID,PxRngRuleID,PxRngProdCmplx,StartPxRng,EndPxRng,PxRngValu</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch/MktDef">
      <xsl:variable name="mktDef" select="concat(@MktID,',',@MktSegID)" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="BaseTrdgRules/PxRngRules">
          <xsl:for-each select="BaseTrdgRules/PxRngRules">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($mktDef, ',', @PxRngRuleID,',',@PxRngProdCmplx,',',@StartPxRng,',',@EndPxRng,',',@PxRngValu,'&#xA;')"/>    
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($mktDef, ',,,,,&#xA;')"/>    
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there was always going to be at least one `PxRngRules` for each `MktDef` (or if you didn't want output `MktDef` elements with no `PxRngRules` you could simplify the code to this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MktID,MktSegID,PxRngRuleID,PxRngProdCmplx,StartPxRng,EndPxRng,PxRngValu</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch/MktDef">
      <xsl:variable name="mktDef" select="concat(@MktID,',',@MktSegID)" />
      <xsl:for-each select="BaseTrdgRules/PxRngRules">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($mktDef, ',', @PxRngRuleID,',',@PxRngProdCmplx,',',@StartPxRng,',',@EndPxRng,',',@PxRngValu,'&#xA;')"/>    
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim C, Thank you for your reply. Its perfect. It is working fine.

Comment: Can I ask you something more on this?

Comment: If I want to add 2 more columns with the values   "QtSideInd and FastMktPctg" in BaseTrdgRules tag, can you tell me how can I do that? Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: You can use `../@QtSideInd` in the concat statment to get the attribute value of the parent.

Comment: Hi Tim C, Could you please look into this post share your Answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632725/how-to-read-xml-data-of-same-child-name-node-from-two-different-parent-nodes-usi. Thank you!