# How to parse complex and recurssive xml file having size 1GB and store it in csv using xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have the sample xml data as shown below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <FIXML s="2012-04-23" v="FIX.5.0SP2">
  <Batch ID="...">
   <MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="14" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="CONF" MarketSegmentDesc="FUT 8-13 Y. SWISS GOV.BONDS 6%" Sym="CH0002741988" ParentMktSegmID="FBND" Ccy="CHF" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="2">
    <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
    .
    .
    </BaseTrdgRules>
  </MktDef>

  <SecDef TxnTm="2016-12-09T07:29:08.483638853">
      <MktSegGrp MktSegID="14">
        <SecTrdgRules>
          <BaseTrdgRules ImpldMktInd="3" MlegModel="0"/>
        </SecTrdgRules>
     </MktSegGrp>
 </SecDef>
 <SecDef>
   <MktSegGrp MktSegID="14">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules ImpldMktInd="3" MlegModel="0"/>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
 </SecDef>
 <SecDef>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="14">
   <SecTrdgRules>
     <BaseTrdgRules ImpldMktInd="3" MlegModel="0"/>
   </SecTrdgRules>
 </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>

<MktDef MktID="XEUR" MktSegID="19629" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-11" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-15" MktSeg="FBON" MarketSegmentDesc="EURO BONO FUTURE 8,5-10,5 YEAR" Sym="DE000A163W29" ParentMktSegmID="FBND" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="2">
     <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">

     </BaseTrdgRules>
</MktDef>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

This is my sample XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MktID,MktSegID,TxnTm,PriSetPx,QtSideInd,FastMktPctg,ImpldMktInd,MlegModel</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch">
      <xsl:variable name="mktDef" select="concat(/Batch/MktDef/@MktID,',',/Batch/MktDef/@MktSegID,',',/Batch/SecDef/@TxnTm,',',/Batch/SecDef/@PriSetPx)" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Batch">
          <xsl:for-each select="Batch">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($mktDef, ',',/Batch/MktDef/BaseTrdgRules/@QtSideInd,',',/Batch/MktDef/BaseTrdgRules/@FastMktPctg,',',/Batch/SecDef/MktSegGrp/SecTrdgRules/BaseTrdgRules/@ImpldMktInd,',',/Batch/SecDef/MktSegGrp/SecTrdgRules/BaseTrdgRules/@MlegModel,'&#xA;')"/>    
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($mktDef, ',,,,,&#xA;')"/>    
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to get the attributes data of "BaseTrdgRules" in both MktDef and SecDef as below,

```
MktID   MktSegID    TxnTm   PriSetPx    QtSideInd   FastMktPctg ImpldMktInd MlegModel
XEUR    14  158.39  2016-12-09T07:29:08.483638853               
XEUR    14  158.39  2016-12-09T07:29:08.483638853   3   0       
XEUR    14  158.39  2016-12-09T07:29:08.483638853   3   0
```

I have written the code in DOM and able to parse the xml. But the problem is memory issue so I have to develop this with something new parser which it can parse large XML files.

Could you please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't quite work out your logic but I think you may benefit from using a key here to look up the `SecDef` element using its `MktSegGrp` attribute value

```
<xsl:key name="MktSeg" match="SecDef" use="MktSegGrp/@MktSegID" />
```

So, for a given `MktDef`, you would get the `SecDef` elements for it like so

```
<xsl:variable name="secDef" select="key('MktSeg', @MktSegID)" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:key name="MktSeg" match="SecDef" use="MktSegGrp/@MktSegID" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>MktID,MktSegID,TxnTm,PriSetPx,QtSideInd,FastMktPctg,ImpldMktInd,MlegModel</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="FIXML/Batch/MktDef">
      <xsl:variable name="secDef" select="key('MktSeg', @MktSegID)" />

      <xsl:for-each select="BaseTrdgRules">
        <xsl:variable name="header" select="concat(../@MktID,',', ../@MktSegID, ',', @QtSideInd, ',', @FastMktPctg)" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$secDef">
            <xsl:for-each select="$secDef">
              <xsl:variable name="baseTrg" select="MktSegGrp/SecTrdgRules/BaseTrdgRules" />
              <xsl:value-of select="concat($header, ',', @TxnTm, ',', @PriSetPx, ',', $baseTrg/@ImpldMktInd, ',', $baseTrg/@MlegModel, '&#xA;')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($header, ',,,,&#xA;')"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim C, Thanks for your help. This code is not helping me to achieve the result and also it is giving me output in one single row in CSV file. I have updated the xml file for having more number of "BaseTrdgRules". Could you please check and let me know if you can manage to get the output. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi Tim C, Can you please suggest me some good sites or materials to learn XSLT from the start to advance level like the code you have written. Thank you very much :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files